# Java Application Window not recognized as java window in C# InterOp

Tags: java, c#, interop, java-access-bridge

I am using Java Access Bridge API with interop in C#. When trying to create a new `AccessibleWindow` with the hwnd obtained from the user32.dll method `GetForegroundWindow()`, it does not recognize the window as a java window, returning null. `IsJavaWindow()` returns false, but calling it a second time returns true. I tested this out with the example "SwingSet2" application.

```
        public void Initialize()
        {
            if(!Initialized)
            {
                accessBridge = new AccessBridge();
                var hwnd = WindowsNativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow();
                var window = accessBridge.CreateAccessibleWindow(hwnd);
                window.AccessBridge.Initialize();
                window.AccessBridge.Functions.GetAccessibleContextFromHWND(hwnd, out vmId, out mainContext);
                Initialized = true;      
            }
        }
```

I am also using code from this repo: [Google Access Bridge](https://github.com/google/access-bridge-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Initialize()` or the initialization code in general needs to called in a UI thread or a message pumping thread.
2. Using the `IntPtr` from `GetForegroundWindow()` or `GetActiveWindow()` always returns false in `IsJavaWindow()`, but using `FindWindow()` works from user32.dll's methods.